# Programatically add document to Hummingbird/OpenText eDocs database

Tags: database, opentext

I am working with the the (formerly Hummingbird Enterprise) OpenText eDocs document management system.

http://www.opentext.com/2/global/products/products-opentext-edocs-products/products-opentext-edocs-document-management.htm

We are still using Hummingbird 5.1.0.5.

I have been reviewing the API docs for this software, but some areas are slightly vague.
So far, I can create my Profile form, populate some values.

```
DOCSObjects.Application docApp = null;
DOCSObjects.IProfile profile = null;
Type fType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("DOCSObjects.Application");
docApp = (DOCSObjects.Application)Activator.CreateInstance(fType);
try { profile = docApp.CurrentLibrary.CreateProfile("DEF_PROF"); }
catch (Exception ex) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
if (profile != null)
{
    try
    {
        profile.Columns["DOCNAME"].Value = "New PDF Document";
        profile.Columns["APP_ID"].Value = "ACROBAT";
        profile.ShowProfile(1);
        // not sure how to set a document here
        profile.SetDocument(docApp.CurrentLibrary.Name, document);
        profile.Save(); // requires a short flag, but what?
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Profile is null");
}
```

Where I am having trouble is how to save a document with the profile.
I am using C# and the API docs and intellisense simply ask for on object for the document.
Does that mean the path or do I need to load the PDF into some specific DOCSObjects type?

Also, the API docs references a Constant such as OF_NORMAL when saving the document. I assume this is 0, but are there others I should know about? There are many Constants referenced in the docs that have no values defined. (All examples are in C++/VB).

I know it's a long shot anyone is using this software, but thought I would give it a try.
Thank you and any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it in VB - using an API wrapper that I created.  You should use the PCDClient under DM API folder instead of the DOCSObjects.

This code here probably won't work right away for you because it is heavily customized, but play around with it and you can probably figure it out.  Good Luck!

```
Public Sub CreateProfile(ByRef Doc As Profile)

    Try
       'SET THE STATIC META DATA
        Doc.objDoc.SetProperty("TYPE_ID", "DOCS") ' DOCUMENT TYPE IS ALWAYS DOCS
        Doc.objDoc.SetProperty("TYPIST_ID", RDIMSAPI._UserID)
        Doc.objDoc.SetProperty("APP_ID", RDIMSData.GetApp(Doc.FileToImport)) ' FILE TO IMPORT

        'CREATE THE DOCUMENT
        Doc.objDoc.Create()
        If Doc.objDoc.ErrNumber <> 0 Then
            Throw New Exception(Doc.objDoc.ErrNumber & " - " & Doc.objDoc.ErrDescription)
        End If

        'RETRIEVE THE NEW DOCUMENT PROFILE
        Dim DocNumber As Integer = Doc.objDoc.GetReturnProperty("%OBJECT_IDENTIFIER")
        Dim VersionID As Integer = Doc.objDoc.GetReturnProperty("%VERSION_ID")

        'ADD THE DOCUMENT TO THE PROFILE
        Dim objPutDoc As New PCDClient.PCDPutDoc
        objPutDoc.SetDST(RDIMSAPI._sDST)
        objPutDoc.AddSearchCriteria("%TARGET_LIBRARY", RDIMSAPI._Library)
        objPutDoc.AddSearchCriteria("%DOCUMENT_NUMBER", DocNumber)
        objPutDoc.AddSearchCriteria("%VERSION_ID", VersionID)
        objPutDoc.Execute()
        If objPutDoc.ErrNumber <> 0 Then
            Throw New Exception(Doc.objDoc.ErrNumber & " - " & Doc.objDoc.ErrDescription)
        End If
        objPutDoc.NextRow()

        'UPLOAD THE DOCUMENT
        Dim objPutStream As PCDClient.PCDPutStream = objPutDoc.GetPropertyValue("%CONTENT")
        Dim fs As FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Doc.FileToImport)
        Dim fi As FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(Doc.FileToImport)
        Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(fs)
        Dim addDocBytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CInt(fs.Length))
        br.Read(addDocBytes, 0, addDocBytes.Length)
        br.Close()
        Dim bytesWritten As Integer = 0
        objPutStream.Write(addDocBytes, addDocBytes.Length, bytesWritten)
        objPutStream.SetComplete()

        'UNLOCK THE DOCUMENT
        Dim objDoc As New PCDClient.PCDDocObject
        objDoc.SetDST(RDIMSAPI._sDST)
        objDoc.SetObjectType("0_RDIMSPROF_SYS")
        objDoc.SetProperty("%TARGET_LIBRARY", RDIMSAPI._Library)
        objDoc.SetProperty("%OBJECT_IDENTIFIER", DocNumber)
        objDoc.SetProperty("%VERSION_ID", VersionID)
        objDoc.SetProperty("%STATUS", "%UNLOCK")
        objDoc.Update()
        objDoc.Fetch()
        objDoc = Nothing
        If Doc.objDoc.ErrNumber <> 0 Then
            Throw New Exception(Doc.objDoc.ErrNumber & " - " & Doc.objDoc.ErrDescription)
        End If

        'RELEASE ALL OBJECTS AND RETURN DOCUMENT NUMBER
        objPutDoc = Nothing

    Catch ex As Exception
        'IF EXCEPTION, LOG ERROR AND DISPLAY MESSAGE
        Throw New Exception("(" & Me.GetType().FullName & "." & New StackTrace(0).GetFrame(0).GetMethod.Name & ") " & ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're still trying. But here's my C# code for this. It's part of a larger module, so it won't work immediately. The *profile* parameter would be for example "DEF_PROF".

This also uses the PCDClientLib. My understanding is that these are serverside libraries, wich you should use only on the server. And that you should use the lib you've already used for clientside code.

```
// All variable prepended with an underscore are class fields etc...
// DMImportException is a custom exception, nothing special really

/// <summary>
/// Import a file into the library previously logged in to.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="profile">The name of the used profile.</param>
/// <param name="profileNameValues">A dictionary of strings containing the profile values wich should be saved for the document.</param>
/// <param name="FileName">The path and filename of the file to import.</param>
public virtual void ImportFile(string profile, Dictionary<string, string> profileNameValues, string FileName)
{
    if (!_isLoggedIn)
    {
        throw new DMImportException("Trying to import a file while not logged in into DM.");
    }

    int totalbyteswritten;
    byte[] bdata;

    bdata = file.readallbytes(filename);

    pcddocobject objdoc = new pcddocobject();
    objdoc.setproperty("%target_library", _library);
    objdoc.setdst(_dst);
    objdoc.setobjecttype(profile);

    foreach(var profilenamevaluepair in profilenamevalues)
    {
        objdoc.setproperty(profilenamevaluepair.key, profilenamevaluepair.value);
    }

    objdoc.create();

    if (objdoc.errnumber != 0)
    {
        throw new dmimportexception("error while creating a new objdoc. check the inner error.", objdoc.errnumber, objdoc.errdescription);
    }

    _docnumber = objDoc.GetReturnProperty("%OBJECT_IDENTIFIER").ToString();
    _versionID = objDoc.GetReturnProperty("%VERSION_ID").ToString();

    PCDPutDoc objPutDoc = new PCDPutDoc();

    objPutDoc.SetDST(_dst);
    objPutDoc.AddSearchCriteria("%TARGET_LIBRARY", _library);
    objPutDoc.AddSearchCriteria("%DOCUMENT_NUMBER", _docNumber);
    objPutDoc.AddSearchCriteria("%VERSION_ID", _versionID);
    objPutDoc.Execute();

    if (objPutDoc.ErrNumber != 0)
    {
        throw new DMImportException("RecentEdit Failure on Execute: Error while trying to get a handle to the newly created doc. Check the inner error.", objPutDoc.ErrNumber, objPutDoc.ErrDescription);
    }

    objPutDoc.NextRow();

    PCDPutStream objPutStream = (PCDPutStream)objPutDoc.GetPropertyValue("%CONTENT");

    objPutStream.Write((object)bdata, (int)bdata.Length, out TotalBytesWritten);

    objPutStream.SetComplete();

    objPutStream = null;
    objDoc = null;

    objDoc = new PCDDocObject();
    objDoc.SetDST(_dst);
    objDoc.SetObjectType(profile);
    objDoc.SetProperty("%TARGET_LIBRARY", _library);
    objDoc.SetProperty("%OBJECT_IDENTIFIER", _docNumber);
    objDoc.SetProperty("%VERSION_ID", _versionID);
    objDoc.SetProperty("%STATUS", "%UNLOCK");
    objDoc.Update();

    if (objDoc.ErrNumber != 0)
    {
        throw new DMImportException("Error while trying to unlock the just imported file. Check the inner error.", objDoc.ErrNumber, objDoc.ErrDescription);
    }

    objPutDoc = null;
    objDoc = null;
    return;
}
```

P.S. I'd recommend you update to a later version of eDocs (we're upgrading from 5.1.0.5 to 5.2.1 end of this week ;-D)

--- EDIT ---

I think you need

```
Application.CurrentLibrary.CreateProfile("PROF_DEF").CreateVersionFromFile( /* filePath is one of the params */);
```

if you really need to do this with the DM Ext. API instead of the DM API